# circuit with one time flashing LED

Tags: led

I'm trying to design a  DC circuit (1.5v or AA battery as powersource)  where the LED turns on for a time less than one second.and it turns off for the rest of the cycle until the power is reapplied.Can anyone come up with a schematic diagram such that the circuit has a high operational time.
Thank You

Comment: zero seconds is less than one second, right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a complete schematic is required. There is no engineering design question.

Answer (score 2):

A capacitor inline with the LED will allow current to flow until the capacitor is charged.

Time constant, current draw and "high operational time" is left as an exercise for the reader.